# Frequency Response Error for IIR Butterworth in GNU Octave

Tags: frequency, octave

I'm wondering why the following code for GNU Octave appears to be incorrect in the frequency domain by a magnitude of 2. For example, in Figure 1. (Sorry, I'm apparently not allowed to post images!) it can be seen that the -3dB points of the bandpass butterworth filter are at 150 and 300Hz instead of the design requirement of 300 and 600Hz. I can't really see that I'm doing wrong?

```
%Start from nothing!
clear;

% Set the sampling frequency used by our digital filtering system:
fs=8000;

% Start designing a butterworth filter, passband. (In Hz)
pass_lo = 300;
pass_hi = 600;

% The order of the filter
order = 4;

% Determine the low and high frequencies of the passband as fractions of the
% sampling rate:
flo = pass_lo/fs;
fhi = pass_hi/fs;

% Use the butterworth filter design function to get the coefficients for a
% bandpass filter with the settings above:
[b,a] = butter(order, [flo fhi]);

% Determine the frequency response of the filter design above. Get the output
% in frequency rather than rad/s. Use 512 plot points.
[H,f] = freqz(b, a, 512, fs);

% Plot the result so that we can see if it is correct:
figure(1);
plot(f, 20*log10(abs(H)));
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');
```

Comment: Post the links to the images in plain text or put them in a comment and someone will edit them in for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about GNU but in Matlab the frequency argument is specified relative to the Nyquist frequency (fs/2) and not the sample rate itself (fs). This makes the maxium legal argument for a relative cutoff frequency 1 (instead of 0.5). Your frequency argument should be [flo fhi]/fs*2.

Comment: Thanks Hilmar, that's exactly right. I found that out afterwards, but apparently I can't answer my own question for 8 hours. Thanks though, teaches me to read the manual more!